# How do I get a O(log n) when I want to sort according to two keys?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have a bunch of nodes, sorted alphabetically according to data, in a Red-Black tree.

```
struct node {
    int counter = 1;
    string data = nullptr;
    int red = 0;
};
```

I used a balanced binary tree because it has a big O(log n).

The counter for the nodes gets incremented if I try to insert a node and the data matches any one of the childs, and/or the root (and the node doesn't get inserted).

I want to print out like maybe the top *n* (let's say 10) nodes ranked from the counter in descending order (highest to lower). But since the nodes are sorted alphabetically according to data and not counter, the best scenario I can think of for searching through an unsorted list is O(n), worst case, using selection or sequential search.

That would make my big O to be O(n+log n), which is essentially a big O(n) - I was hoping to achieve something faster.

My question is how can I go about to achieve the big O I want, that is, anything, faster than a  O(n)?

Comment: you could build up a sorted list with pointers to the same nodes, sorted by the counter. That would give you O(1) when searching the top n counters, but would increase the overhead when inserting elements.

Comment: That makes sense, an off-topic question but how much overhead is there? If I had, say a huge number, like 100,000 nodes, would creating a separate list be faster (measured like with chronos) than adding a few comparisons like when I insert nodes?

Comment: when accessing the top x counters it is faster to have a sorted list, where you take the front or rear x elements (O(1)), when inserting the overhead is probably between O(n) and O(log(n)) depending on how you implement the sorted List. The memory overhead is probably not that huge, as you would only use the pointers.

Comment: Whatever the solution will be, you should test it against an `std::vector` because CPUs fed properly by your prefetcher are really, really fast. Stroustrup tested generating N random numbers and inserting them into a `std::vector` and a `std::list` at the correct (i.e. so that the range stayed sorted) place, then deleting them in random order. The `vector` owned the `list` even for big N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the data in a binary tree sorted by `data` is just like having it in an array with no specific order with respect to queries based on `count`. Thus you can not do anything better than linear for a single query. If you plan to perform the query multiple times it may be worth it to have an alternative structure ordered by counter. If all you need to support is query for top 10 a binary heap will do just great. If you plan to only perform a few queries you can not improve the performance too much.

Comment: I haven't thought about the amount of times I query but I don't think it'll be much. And that makes sense! I'll use what @Theolodis suggested, and make another list using pointer reference